# Few Selenium Test Cases are skipping In Jenkins build Execution

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Issue:

(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

[Jenkins Build Execution Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDVR.png)

Currently, I am using Windows Jenkins Machine with 32 bit with below versions
Selenium-Java dependency version : 4.14.1
ChromeDriver version: 119.0.6045.105
Chrome Browser version: 119.0.6045.160
JDK and JRE - 17

**My Try:**

1. I have Uninstalled Chrome Browser and Restarted Jenkins Machine and ReInstalled Chrome Browser --> Still skipped few test cases
2. WebDriverManager used Instead of chromedriver.exe path --> Still Skipped Few test cases
3. Upgraded Selenium-Java 4.14.1 version to - 4.15.0 --> Still Skipped Few test cases
4. Used setBinary chromeoptions and set chromedriver.exe path to it ---> Still Skipped Few test cases

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.